# Appended group of rows as jquery response do not respect table-striped table style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a first table response from a first form submitting. The table uses the defined boostrap.css style n.table-striped set to white bg for odd rows:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="offers-product">
```

and in boostrap.css

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

The back-end return the first 10 results; in case the end user desires to get 10 more there is a button "MORE RESULTS" that on click trigger the following jquery code:

```
function show_offers(render, from_item, to_item, products_id_list, searchedGeneric, searchedMade, searchedCountries, searchedFormats, searchedCurrency){

      if (render == 'PCRender') {

   $.ajax({
      method:'POST',
      url: ajax_url+'frontController/addRenderPCScreenOffers',
      data:{  render:render,
              from_item:from_item,
              to_item:to_item,
              products_id_list:products_id_list,
              searchedGeneric:searchedGeneric,
              searchedMade:searchedMade,
              searchedCountries:searchedCountries,
              searchedFormats:searchedFormats,
              searchedCurrency:searchedCurrency
           },
      dataType:'text',

      success:function(res)
      { 
        $("#offers-product").append(res);
      }

   });   

}

}
```

Obviously, res has the proper html rows code. The problem is that the added rows do not respect the table style table-striped so that the odd lines have the same bk of the even ones; just the added rows, the first ones are ok. How could I get that also the added rows will respect the correct table style alternating their bk color?

Comment: could you add a sample of **res**? Add console.log(res); after append. Thanks

Comment: You might need to get inside the table body tag e.g. $("#offers-product tbody")

Comment: It seems likely that the elements are being appended to the `<table>` and not to the `<tbody>`, which is what your CSS relies upon.

Comment: @David Thomas: you are right i have <table> <tbody> [frst correct rows] </tbody> [added rows] <\table> So how could i use JS/jQuery to add the new rows in the proper place? Any specific one-line command? maybe how suggested by kasper Jalvas Jensen $("#offers-product tbody")?

Comment: Yeah, that should work perfectly well (I see you've posted an answer detailing that, now). Best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestions of @Kasper Halvas Jensen and @David Thomas fixed the trouble, thanks. So to summarize i have replaced this

```
$("#offers-product").append(res);
```

with this

```
$("#offers-product tbody").append(res);
```